# quantum entanglement of 3 or more quanta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have 2 questions i would really like to find an answer to:
if we have a quantum pair, we can determine whether 2 quanta are entangled or not assuming that we have access to the information of both of them. 
so if we have a quantum "trio" instead of a quantum pair, does the information about 2 out of 3 quanta suffice to determine whether those two quanta are entangled? if not, why not.
the only entanglement i am interested in is the one of the 2 quanta that are tested. the 3rd one is not important for question one.
the second question is: if one out of those 3 entangled particles wave functions collapses, this should break the entanglement of all 3 particles and collapse their wave-functions, right?

this is a rephrased version of my original question, in hopes that there would be less confusion.

original question was:

It is my understanding that you can entangle multiple quanta, so that you don't get "quantum pairs" but for example "quantum-trios" etc. I base this assumption on the following study: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13251 Further I believe to know that once the wave function of an entangled particle is collapsed, the entanglement is "broken". I know that there are several resctrictions for faster than light communication with a quantum pair/quantum pairs. I do base following thought experiment on the assumption that one does need only access to the information about 2 out of three quanta to determine whether an entanglement is existent or not.

If we assume a entanglement of atleast 3 quanta(trio) and person (A) has 1 quantum, person (B) has two quanta and person (A) collapses the wave-function, (B) should be able to determine that his 2 quanta are no longer entangled, and faster than light communication would be possible. I don't think it is that simple, but I lack the knowledge. What am I missing?

Comment: What does "having access to the information about them" mean?  Does it mean full knowledge of their state?  If so, then the answer is that yes, given a state it is quite easy to determine whether that state is entangled.  Otherwise, your question is incomprehensible until you reveal what "the information" means.

Comment: As for your second question, what does "collapse their wave functions" mean here?  Obviously the observation of #3 affects the state of #1 and #2.  What properties would the new state have to have before you considered it "collapsed"?

Comment: lets say we have an array of entangled photon-trios for each bit of information we want to send(per bit an array of lets say 100 trios). now we can use stochastic to determine entanglement. we collapse the wave-function by measuring the spin. if the entanglement is: 1_2, 2_3 and 1_3 for each trio (numbers represent photons), and person (A) has photons 1 and (B) has photons 2+3. (B) can now measure the spin of his 2's and 3's, and if his statistics tell him that they have the expected spins he knows the entanglement was intact. or not?

Comment: Again: the state of the 1's is not important for (B) according to my thought experiment. but when the wave-function of 1's is collapsed, the entanglement 1_2 and 1_3 is broken.

Comment: in this case, 2's and 3's wave-function collapses, and entanglement 2_3 is broken too. this can be detected by testing 2's and 3's for entanglement 2_3.

Comment: I have no idea what the notation in your comments means.

Comment: maybe if you would bother to read properly you wouldn't have such a hard time understanding what i am talking about: "numbers represent photons". in a photontrio there are 3 photons. 1_2 represents entanglement between photon 1 and 2 out of the trio. i really don't see the problem.

Comment: maybe if you would bother to read properly you wouldn't have such a hard time understanding the question.   I know what it means for the state of the trio to be entangled.   I know what it would mean for the state of the first pair to be entangled, if the first pair had a state. But  if the trio is entangled, then no pair has a state of its own, so I have no idea what it means to say that any given pair is entangled.  And since you are inventing this scenario, the only hope for knowing what it means is for you to tell us.  Please write down a state for the trio that satisfies your intentions.

Comment: "But if the trio is entangled, then no pair has a state of its own, so I have no idea what it means to say that any given pair is entangled." lets try simplify my line of questions.
 as soon as the wave-function of one of the entangled photons in a trio is collapsed, the entanglement is broken. thats afaik how multipartite entanglement works. simple yes or no.

Comment: "But if the trio is entangled, then no pair has a state of its own, so I have no idea what it means to say that any given pair is entangled."
if we measure the spin of 1, the wave function collapses, the entanglement 1_2+1_3+2_3 breaks down, the wave-function of 2 and 3 collapses, we can make a prediction for 2 and 3's spin and prove it with stochastics. and now simply imagine the same process, but we don't make any measurements OR assumptions about 3. surely we still can detect the same statistical correlations for 2's and 1's spin. yes or no.

Comment: If you plan to make an observation of Particle 1 with eigenstates $A$ and $B$, then you can write the state of the triple as $A\otimes  X+B\otimes Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are states for the other pair.  Now make your measurement, and the state of the other pair collapses into either $X$ or $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ can be absolutely anything.   If you're trying to get an answer that goes beyond "anything can happen", you're going to have to specify something more about the properties of the initial state, in language that somebody other than you can understand.

Comment: let me rephrase again.
given i know that the particles are entangled and i have access to the information about their spin:
if i have an entangled photonpair that's entangled and measure the spin of one and it has an upspin, the other one has a downspin, right?
if i have an entangled photontrio, and measure the spin of one and it has an upspin, the other two have downspins, right?

Comment: one can use interference of two entangled particles to determine their entanglement, right?

Comment: For the 810th time, nobody can answer your question untill you specify the initial state.

Comment: what kind of question is that, i ask for a simple yes or no. as an analogy, if i ask someone if it is possible to break glass with an explosion, the answer is simply yes. makes no sense for him to ask how strong the explosion or the glass is, that is not part of the question. i didn't ask a specific question, i asked a general one.
so why would you need me to define their initial state if i just want to know a simple yes or no answer to my question. IS IT POSSIBLE TO DETERMINE ENTANGLEMENT BETWEEN 2 QUANTA IN A MULTIPARTITE SYSTEM WITH ONLY INFORMATION ABOUT THOSE 2 QUANTA.

Comment: Your question is not analogous to asking whether it is possible to break glass with an explosion.  It is analogous to asking whether it is possible to break glass with a gleep --- and then ignoring repeated requests to tell us what a "gleep" is.  In a system with three particles, there is no clear meaning to the phrase "entanglement between 2 quanta".   It is a phrase every bit as mysterious and meaningless as the word "gleep".  If you mean something by that phrase, you need to tell us what that meaning is.  The word "gleep" does not become clearer if you keep repeating it.

Comment: In any event:  The trick you seem to be missing (perhaps because you were too agitated to read my earlier comment) is to write the initial state in the form $\sum\alpha_{ij}C_i\otimes D_j$ where the $C_i$ are eigenstates of the meansurement you plan to make on one particle and the $D_j$ are in the state space for the remaining pair.  Clearly a measurement can collapse the remaining pair into any of the states $D_j$.  Now if you **write down your assumptions** on the $D_j$ (in particular, if you  specify what you **mean** by your assumptions about entanglement between particles 1 and 2) then...

Comment: ...the answer is that the allowable $D_j$ are precisely those that can satisfy your (until  now unstated) assumptions.

Comment: i need to look into the math of quantum entanglement, i never bothered so far because my curiosity was easily satisfied with simple explanations. i got some more detailed explanation as to why my thoughtexperiment doesn't work in an other forum(https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/quantum-entanglement-wave-function-collapse.929967/#post-5871309), but i still can't quite wrap my head around it. the advice to look closer at the math seems reasonable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we have a quantum "trio" instead of a quantum pair, does the information about 2 out of 3 quanta suffice to determine whether those two quanta are entangled?

**No**, it is not sufficient.

A simple counter-example is given by [GHZ states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state), 
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{|000\rangle + |111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
which have maximal tripartite entanglement but for which the tracing out of any of the three systems leaves behind a maximally mixed bipartite state
$$
\rho_{12} = \mathrm{Tr}_3(|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|) = \frac{|00\rangle \langle00|+|11\rangle\langle11|}{2}
\tag{$*$}
$$
which has exactly zero bipartite entanglement. That means that there is provably no measurement that's confined to particles 2 and 3 that's going to be able to distinguish whether the tripartite state is a pure GHZ with maximal tripartite entanglement or the maximally mixed state
$$
\rho_\mathrm{maximally\ mixed} = \frac{|000\rangle \langle000|+|111\rangle\langle111|}{2}
$$
with zero tripartite entanglement.

---

As for your second question,

> if one out of those 3 entangled particles wave functions collapses

that's an undefined statement and as posed it is essentially meaningless. Wavefunction collapse is not spontaneous, and it is always relative to a given basis (i.e. relative to a given projective measurement). In this situation, a projective measurement on the third particle can, depending on the choice of measurement basis, either kill all the entanglement, or instate maximal bipartite entanglement (given classical communication from party 3 to parties 1 and 2).

- If you measure along the computational basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ of the third qubit, then that reduces the 1-2 bipartite states to either $|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$ (that's *if* you communicate the measurement results from 3 to 1 and 2; otherwise, you just get the maximally mixed state $(*)$), neither of which are entangled.
- Alternatively, if you measure along the $\sigma_x$ basis $\{|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle),|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)\}$, then a result along $|+\rangle$ will project the 1-2 bipartite state onto the Bell state
  $$|\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
  and a result along $|-\rangle$ will project the it onto
  $$|\Phi^-\rangle = \frac{|00\rangle - |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},$$
  both of which have maximal bipartite entanglement.

  However, it is important to note that for this bipartite entanglement to be useful, you *need* to know which of the two states you have (i.e. party 3 needs to communicate its measurement outcome to the other two parties along a classical (and therefore slower-than-light) communication channel). If you don't, then you're reduced to the incoherent addition of their density matrices,
  $$\rho = \frac{|\Phi^+\rangle \langle\Phi^+|+|\Phi^-\rangle \langle\Phi^-|}{2}  = \frac{|00\rangle \langle00|+|11\rangle\langle11|}{2},$$
  i.e. the maximally-mixed bipartite state with zero bipartite entanglement.

---

And, finally, touching on one of your remarks,

> ... and faster than light communication would be possible...

please burn this into the inside of your skull:

- [**quantum entanglement is *never* a route to faster-than light communication.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem)

There's a reason why the No-Communication Theorem is called a theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer, i appreciate it very much.

"And, finally, touching on one of your remarks,

... and faster than light communication would be possible..."

i think essential here is to read that sentence in context, and especially pay attention to the last sentence:
"... and faster than light communication would be possible. I don't think it is that simple, but I lack the knowledge. What am I missing?"
I knew right from the start that it is not possible, and implicated so three times:
1.i don't think it is that simple 2. i lack the knowledge 3. what am i missing

Comment: 4. what am i missing
just want to point that out. apart from your last remark, your contribution was very useful though. would've been nice if i got an answer like yours right from the start, would've made things much easier and less frustrating.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with lacking the knowledge, that's why you asked and that's why I answered. And the very first bit of relevant knowledge is the No-Communication Theorem, whose importance is hard to overstate.

Comment: Also, I appreciate that some of the responses you got were suboptimal, but to be frank the question's phrasing was hardly helpful and you got pretty abrasive pretty fast; I was very close to skipping this one based on the assessed risk that it would lead to a belligerent and abrasive comment thread. I mean, in case you find that feedback useful for future threads.